# Error saving rules - Line 2: Expected '"'. on my Firebase Realtime Database Rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

this is my first time.
it's giving me this error on Firebase Realtime Database Rules

> Error saving rules - Line 2: Expected '"'.

```js
{
  rules_version: '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
    match /posts/{postId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

i was expecting it would work?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are mixing up [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) and the [Realtime Database (RTDB)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database). Your rules are for Firestore (`service cloud.firestore`, with an extra set of curly brackets around it) but it seems you use the RTDB.

Rules for the RTDB are documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax?hl=en).

---

If you do use Firestore you need to remove the outer curly brackets: [Firestore rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure?hl=en#service_and_database_declaration) begin as follows:

```
rules_version: '2';   // Optional
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {...}
}
```